# Interactive 3d modelling program

Tags: silverlight, flash, 3d, shockwave

**Question:**

I look for a program that can do the job for the following questions:

1. On a website the user can see a animated 'movie' of a house exterior
2. He can rotate the house left-right, up-down
3. When he clicks on, lets say a door, a price and some text will show up

.

**About the framework the program uses:**

Please no unity3d or another animation framework that is not widely used. Maybe Flash, Shockwave or Silverlight?

.

**The questioned program:**

It may be a program that a most company use in this scenario. But at best a program that can be used by semi-profs like I think i am ;-)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need a 3d package to export your module assets (e.g. wall, window, furniture, etc.), then you can use a 3d library to load those models and add the functionality you need(user clicks on door-text gets displayed,etc.) At the moment, I would say Away3DLite/Away3D would be your easiest choices. As @Dennis mentioned Flash Player 11 will have harware acceleration, which means more complex meshes can be used, without loss in framerate. Also, bare in mind that WebGL is supported now in Firefox4 and Chrome. With both hardware accelerated, you need to be aware of your target & supported GPUs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Flash for this.

There are several open source 3D libraries such as:

- http://away3d.com/
- http://blog.papervision3d.org/
- http://www.flashsandy.org/
- http://alternativaplatform.com/en/
- ...

Furthermore, you will be able to leverage GPU acceleration natively in the Flash Player 11.0 release.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks! Do you also know a program where I can design/modelling 3D flash?

Comment: Yes.. do you know such a program?